# Capture button click event of webform 2 in webform1

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 webforms the closeporject button in webform 1 redirects to Webform 2 and asks whether do you really want to close the project. How can I capture the button click event of webform 2 in webform 1 ? 
Someone told me it has to do something with querystring in address bar. 
I am not allowed to use javascript to display my message box.

Comment: because I am not allowed to use javascript in my program to display a messagebox

Answer (score 3):

You can post data from one page to the other. Here from Page2.aspx to Page1.aspx as

On the page2, you set  PostBackUrl on the button that say Continue/Select what ever.

```
PostBackUrl="Page1.aspx"
```

and on Page1.aspx you set where can read the posted data.

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Page2.aspx" %>
```

and you get the data as

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    if(Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
    {
        // here you can get from Page2.aspx==PreviousPage
        //  a check box check, what ever you like...
        GetTheClass = PreviousPage.MyDataClass;
    }
}
```

relative: [Cross-page posting. Is it a good pratice to use PreviousPage in Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124030/cross-page-posting-is-it-a-good-pratice-to-use-previouspage-in-asp-net/10124789)

More about Cross Page posting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx