# Best Way to transfer data From one page to another In asp.net.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In my scenario am using java-script popup that popups another form which is an address entry form of merely 20 Controls in it. Now I retrieving data from address page to main page by using a session variable which stores a data table of values. Two different Session variables are this way used for permanent and temporary addresses.

Using session variable degrades the performance i know.

What is the best way to transfer value from one page to another?

Comment: Do you save the data into database after closing the popup?

Comment: keeps data in a datatable then on save btn click entire data is saved.

Comment: That save button is located on popup or the parent form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is the cross posting, describe it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(VS.100).aspx

You can also read more about at that question/answer: [Cross-page posting. Is it a good pratice to use PreviousPage in Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124030/cross-page-posting-is-it-a-good-pratice-to-use-previouspage-in-asp-net)

Comment: But the problem is that address is a common popup.. So that i can't specify the post back URL as <asp:Button ID="btnOk" Runat="server" Text="OK"

         PostBackUrl="EmployeeDetils.aspx" />

Comment: But the problem is that address is a common popup.. So that i can't specify the post back URL as <asp:Button ID="btnOk" Runat="server" Text="OK"  PostBackUrl="EmployeeDetils.aspx" />. The registry <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/address.aspx" %> in employee details also ambiguous for me that the registry declares addres.aspx as the previous page for EmployeeDetils.aspx but its not true always.