# ASP.NET's Forms Rule, Only One Form Per Page: Using a Master page with a Log in Form, what about the Register page?

Tags: asp.net, forms

Usually in Master page, I put the stuff that I would like to see on all pages, the common stuff, and one of those common stuff are two innocent TextBox with a Button, to be able to log in, that's a Form.

And I have another page, which is the Register page, that's another Form.

I can't use 2 runat="server" forms, so what is the solution for this? The idea that no website written in ASP.NET that has no common log in box in the header can't get into my head...

Comment: Time to move on to MVC, where there is no such restriction?

Comment: But I'm working on a project for my University, so Web Forms are a must.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124030/cross-page-posting-is-it-a-good-pratice-to-use-previouspage-in-asp-net/10124789#10124789

Answer (score 0):

Just forget runat='server', back to the html.

Your login form could be

```
<form action="/loginaction.aspx" method="post">
  <input name="Username" />
  <input name="Password" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="sign in" />
</form>
```

and then put code in the `PageLoad` method of your loginaction.aspx page to process the login request. It maybe looks like this:

```
string name = Request["Username"];
string password = Request["Password"];
// do login..
```

BTW: What a pity that asp.net developer can not work without `runat='server'` ...

Comment: But then..what about ASP Validators?

Comment: I'm working on another solution. I will make a Login.aspx page, put the form inside it, then using the jquery .load function to load that page inside a DIV in the master page, maybe it will work.

Comment: @user1665700 Unfortunately, I don't think it will work. You should understand more about the way that how an asp.net page works